# socket.io not working for simple use case

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

```
var app = require("http").createServer(handler); // handler defined below
var io = require("socket.io")(app);
var fs = require('fs');
app.listen(8080);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + "/index.html",
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end("Error loading index.html");
    }
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("Hell World");
  });
}


io.on('connection', function(socket){
  socket.on('dataChanged', function(data){console.log("Hello World")});
})

io.emit('dataChanged', 'this is a test')

//index.html
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:8080');
  socket.on('dataChanged', function(data){console.log("Hello World")});
</script>
```

I am trying to implement this trivial feature but it is not working.Where am i going wrong i dont see the logs. socket events are not registered.

Comment: Could you post your index.html file as well ?

Answer (score 1):

Alright three things here.

**1.** Your `res.end` is sending `Hell world` but it should send `data`

`res.end("Hell World");`

should be

`res.end(data);`

*This is because we want to display the index.html file not a hello world*

**2.**  Your index.html is calling the socket.io js file wrong

`<script src="/node_modules/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

should be

`<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>`

*This is because you cannot reference a file like that because there is no logic for it in your code. socket.io does however have the logic for it and can be called this way*

**3.** Use emit on the client side

In your index.html change this code

`socket.on('dataChanged', function(data){console.log("Hello World")});`

to

`socket.emit('dataChanged', 'this is a test')`

and remove

`io.emit('dataChanged', 'this is a test')`

from your nodejs file

**Now you can see Hello World from your console**

Comment: Still nothing. No logs yet, with the above changes. By the way when i do npm install socket.io. It gets added to the node_modules folder, so should the path not be for that ? Else where is this /socket.io/socket.io.js file?

Comment: @shiv I have edited my answer, Also the /socket.io/socket.io.js file is from socket.io module. You do not have to serve this file yourself

Comment: This change is not working, also what if I want to emit a server side event and want the client to register it.

Comment: I'm having no problems with the code, I can see hello world in my nodejs console. If you want a server to emit you can do so via this example I made: http://pastebin.com/tMVBYLPn

Comment: could you please tell me your version of socket.io, i will try to use that one.

Comment: @shiv socket.io version 1.3.7

Answer (score 0):

When I was trying to create a simple chat using socket.io I had a conneciton problem, I assume that you have the same problem: I've used the same `io.connect('http://localhost:8080')` but later I tried using the IP address of my computer in WiFi network to connect from other devices (because localhost points to current device) - so the IP address of my computer in WiFi network was `192.168.0.103` -> `io.connect('http://192.168.0.103')` or `io.connect('http://192.168.1.103')`. I hope this works (the code was for Front-End side).